# how to change capability required to view an admin page?

Tags: capabilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hooking into add_submenu_page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71303/hooking-into-add-submenu-page)

This plugin uses add_menu_page function to create an admin page and I was wondering is there a way to change the capability that is set by this function for this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can club it with `remove_menu_page` to first remove the page & then re-adding it

Copy the `add_menu_page` line from plugin. Paste it in your theme & change the capability. Then immediately before this line add `remove_menu_page($menu_page_slug);`

Use the same hook but with a higher priority